# Log Full GCs only

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm-arguments

I have a few long running Java processes. There are tonnes of GCs that happen, which I usually don't care much about. However, I do care about Full GCs, if they happen in quick succession or take too long.

I wonder if there are any JVM arguments out there which can help me suppress regular GC logging and allow only Full GCs to get printed (I am not looking for any alerts, just logs). Of course, one could do some bit of custom, but simple filtering to get to this, but an out of box support could be very handy. Any ideas?